# Ionic & Angular - Reusable 'next page' button

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I am building a game with Angular and Ionic 3 and since the game has a lot of pages/views, I want to eliminate writing the same code in the ts file of the pages I have buttons.

My question is the following, is it possible to create a '**reusable**' button that moves the current view to another one? What I mean by 'reusable' is to declare the button click function in app.ts and change the destination page dynamically from the HTML.

What I have done so far:

in home.html

```
<button ion-button color="light" (click)="moveToPage(gameSettings)">One Player</button>
```

Note:
The page class I want to go to is "gameSetting" which is part of my project in /pages/game-settings/

in app.ts

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    moveToPage(pageName: String)
    {
        this.navCtrl.push(pageName);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work! What happens is that the HTML passes 'pageName' as a variable with an `undefined` type i.e. it throws an error. The navCtrl page of Ionic only explains how to move to another page by explicitly the page name in the this.navCtrl.push() function. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Any help regarding this behaviour would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your pageName variable in HTML? I mean, where do you give it a value?

Comment: Fair point, I will update the HTML file to eliminate the confusion now. What I want to do is to pass the name of the page I want to go to in HTML.

Comment: @GianlucaParis, your previous answer was right, while trying to get the plunker done I fixed a typo in my code so you did answer my question. Feel free to add your answer below

Comment: Thank you, I added my answer again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to change `(click)="moveToPage(gameSettings)"` to `(click)="moveToPage('gameSettings')"`. Just missing the `''`

Comment: That actually helps, but now I get the following error: `Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: gameSettings`. Just for debugging purposes, I changed the navigation function to this.navCtrl.push(gameSettings); and it works... I have no idea why it is breaking now

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a plunker?